# cmd properties and default settings out of sync

Tags: cmd

When I open my cmd, the window opens, but it is really small.
The properties are:

```
screen buffer Size 
  width : 18
  width : 5
window Size 
  width : 18
  width : 5
```

even though my default setting are:

```
    screen buffer Size 
      width : 80
      width : 25
    window Size 
      width : 80
      width : 20
```

What i have tried: changing the default settings, changing the reg.
Changing the properties works, but only for one session.